# Cramer-Rao type bound for Information Gain

Tags: bayesian, variance, kullback-leibler, loss-functions, decision-theory

I am interested in the Bayes risk of some distribution $\pi$
$$
r(\pi) = \mathbb{E}_{\pi(x)}[ \mathbb{E}_{\Pr(y|d,x)}[L(x,\hat x(y|d))]], 
$$
where $L$ is some loss function and $\hat x$ is the posterior mean (here: Bayes estimator).  Here $d$ is some experimental design parameter.

If $L(x,\hat x) = |x-\hat x|^2$ (squared error), then the **Posterior Cramer-Rao bound** gives a lower bound on the Bayes risk.  The Bayes risk is also identical to the expected posterior variance.  So to optimally design experiments, I can use **negative expected variance** as a utility function to maximize.

Now I would like to reverse this logic to find the effective loss function and a lower bound for **information gain** as an alternative utility function.  That is, suppose the utility function I use is information gain.  Then,

1. What is the loss function which this is optimizing?
2. What is a lower bound on the Bayes risk for this loss function?

Comment: Generalization bounds are in this spirit: http://videolectures.net/mlss05us_langford_gb/

Comment: @Tristan - Thanks. Interesting and certainly seems relevant.  Although, I'm not sure yet whether it answers my specific question--maybe I just need a better question, though.